# FetchError: node-fetch is returning "invalid json response body" when doing intervals

Tags: node.js, json, fetch

I'm making a script that pulls the last json object and then within a range, updates the API to compare if any changes occur, but even compiling the script it returns it to me while in the range:

**FetchError: invalid json response body at http://v3.blet.in/api/badges reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Follow the script:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const url = 'http://v3.blet.in/api/badges'

fetch(url)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
    var embAnt = data[data.length-1].code
    console.log('Online')
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
        fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            var ultEmb = data[data.length-1].code
            if (ultEmb == embAnt) {
                return;
            }
            else if (embAnt != ultEmb) {
                embAnt = ultEmb
                console.log(embAnt)
            }
            else {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: if the code is badly done, sorry because i'm new to programming

Comment: It did work on my machine, you might've tried the API when it was under maintenance or something, so it responded with `html` data causing **`<`** to be in the first position, or it might be blocked in your region, try visiting the API link within your browser

Comment: I can access the API link without any problem, and on my machine it also works normal, the problem occurs when about 5 minutes have passed, then the error starts to appear